# android tabs are too big

Tags: java, android

### Rephrasing an old question as suggested by a group of mods.

Why are android tabs too big ,specially on a device that small? 
Eg. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

I am converting a java Swing application to android and tabs are giving me the most trouble. Besides looking ugly, each page seem to require a separate activity too. I mean with a JtabbedPane all I did was to put whatever components on a separate JPanel and add them to the host pane.

### Thanks

First I believe both of my questions are stated clearly in the above post but i will rephrase anyway

a) Why are the default android tabs so big compared to other components.
It takes up a lot of space of the limited available space. If it is to make it comfortable
for the user why aren't the other components equally big ?

b) [ANSWERED]Why does each page requires starting a separate activity. In my app for example I just need to display some chats. This is already answered i.e use of Fragments.

Hope it is clear enough now

Comment: Android's UI and Java's Swing have little to nothing in common. The reason for this is BECAUSE the screen is so small. If the tabs were the same size as in a Swing application, you would have trouble trying to select them. The screen size is what made it necessary to do something completely different

Comment: If anything you save space by making them smaller so I disagree. I have noted many apps using buttons and handling the switching themselves than using default tabs. Unfortunately for me I have used tabs everywhere in views of the java app.

Comment: Then this sounds like a personal problem. If it's such a big deal, use buttons. Make a new TabActivity class that draws things the way you want them. You're never *required* to use the tabs they offer you, so by all means do whatever you want. Just be aware you'll probably run into countless problems along the way, specifically [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)

Comment: Do you realize the keyboard buttons have much smaller size than the tabs and yet you don't complain about difficulty of selecting them ?

Comment: That's because there's a software behind it accounting for inaccuracy.

Comment: Well why not use that for the other components too ? It is part of the OS I suppose. Facts is the tabs do have a strangely bigger size than what one would expect compared to other components. Your reasoning  that it is because the screen is small is simply wrong.

Comment: You can't use the autocorrect software for tabs. It wouldn't work, the user would get frustrated. By all means, *do it your own way*, but that's way more work. Just make sure you [keep it pure](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html). And in the future, don't come on SO just to complain that Android's UI doesn't look the way you want it to.

Comment: You are not making any sense at all and stop using capital letters to try and convince me. My objection to your post was that your emphatic "BECAUSE it is so small" is wrong. If that was the reason the other controls should be equally big too. Why is it that the tabs are the only one which are x-large ? There is definitely a reason to it but you certainly don't seem to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about the multiple activities problem , check out the [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) solution that google has offered since android 3.x. they also have a compatability package for older android devices (requires android API4+ , which is the vast majority) .

they even have a tabs example which is very similar to the android market app (aka "play store")  , so all you need is to check out the sample.

about tabs sizes , you can customize it however you wish (example [here](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)) , but do note that this requires the user to actually be able to touch it , even with large fingers... :)

Comment: Thanks. I should be able to use the fragments solution since I am targeting a galaxy nexus android. I will have to decrease the height of the tabs because I am creating them everywhere dynamically (multiple chats with users). It might not be the best app with this one-to-one translation but I will try it anyway. P.S you mean the phone Google invented on april 1st that uses the morse code :)

Comment: i don't understand the morse code question . anyway , are you sure you wish to target phones with android ICS (API 14+) ? they are only 5% of the market currently . look : : http://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-sdk-versions http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html most devices currently use version 2.1 and above .

Comment: I can switch to 2.1 or 2.3 I guess since I do not use much of the new features anyway. I use the galaxy nexus because the app I am developing really needs all the space it can get. The gmail tap is an april 1st joke that uses morse code for people with fat fingers. 
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/04/01/gmail-tap-google-april-fools-day_n_1394635.html

Comment: i know the morse code app , i just didn't understand what it has to do with anything i've written about . about the space , do you mean screen space or storage space ? if it's screen space , consider using a scrollView for smaller screens (or something similar) , and if it's storage space , consider using android expansion library : http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html

Comment: Sigh.. it was not a question really.  You said people with large fingers should touch the keys and then put a _smiley_ on it. I interpreted that as a joke. Why so dense?  Well thanks for the rest of your post anyway..

Comment: sorry . i didn't mean it . anyway , do you know that this app actually exists : https://play.google.com/store/search?q=morse+keyboard&c=apps

Comment: I actually didn't know it existed and took it as a joke when I read it. Thanks.